# Как CSS лоадер преобразовать в SVG лоадер?

Tags: css3, html5, svg, анимация, svg-animation

Коллеги, помогите этот пример на `css` полностью перевести в `SVG`, так как хочу его использовать не только на всю страницу, то и на более мелких объектах типа  слайдер...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
  top: calc(50% - 150px);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.border-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #6fba82;
  border-top: 3px solid #f79533;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ef4e7b;
  border-right: none;
  box-shadow: 
  inset 1px 8px 2px 5px #f79533, 
  2px 7px 2px 5px #f37055, 
  inset 3px 6px 2px 5px #ef4e7b, 
  4px 5px 2px 5px #a166ab, 
  inset 5px 4px 2px 5px #5073b8, 
  6px 3px 2px 5px #1098ad, 
  inset 7px 2px 2px 5px #07b39b, 
  8px 1px 2px 5px #6fba82;
  animation: main-rotate 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes main-rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 
    inset 1px 8px 2px 5px #f79533, 
    2px 7px 2px 5px #f37055, 
    inset 3px 6px 4px 5px #ef4e7b, 
    4px 5px 2px 5px #a166ab, 
    inset 5px 4px 6px 5px #5073b8, 
    6px 3px 2px 5px #1098ad, 
    inset 7px 2px 8px 5px #07b39b,
    8px 1px 2px 5px #6fba82;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 
    inset 1px 8px 6px 5px #ADFF2F, 
    2px 7px 2px 5px #7FFF00, 
    inset 3px 6px 6px 5px #7CFC00, 
    4px 5px 2px 5px #00FF00, 
    inset 5px 4px 4px 5px #32CD32, 
    6px 3px 2px 5px #98FB98, 
    inset 7px 2px 2px 5px #90EE90, 
    8px 1px 2px 5px #00FA9A;
  }
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    box-shadow: 
    inset 1px 8px 2px 5px #f79533, 
    2px 7px 2px 5px #f37055, 
    inset 3px 6px 4px 5px #ef4e7b, 
    4px 5px 2px 5px #a166ab, 
    inset 5px 4px 6px 5px #5073b8, 
    6px 3px 2px 5px #1098ad, 
    inset 7px 2px 8px 5px #07b39b, 
    8px 1px 2px 5px #6fba82;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="border-wrap">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Дополнительные эффекты

***Анимация градиента кольца лоадера***

Будем анимировать атрибут  линейного градиента `stop-color`

```
<linearGradient id="gradl" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow"/>   
        </linearGradient>
```

```css
svg {
background:black;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 300 300" > 
<defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradl" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"> 
             <animate attributeName="stop-color"
               dur="1.5s"
               values="dodgerblue;yellow;dodgerblue"
               repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
          </stop>    
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow">
           <animate
             attributeName="stop-color"
             dur="1.5s"
             values="yellow;dodgerblue;yellow"
             repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>       
   
        </linearGradient> 
  
 
     </defs>
<path id="path1" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z"  fill="url(#gradl)" stroke="none" fill-opacity="1" > 
 
</path>

<circle cx="150" cy="150" r="90" stroke="none" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

**Аналогично делаем анимацию градиента второго кольца**

```css
svg {
background:black;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 300 300" > 
<defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradl" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"> 
             <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.5s" values="dodgerblue;yellow;dodgerblue" repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>    
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow">
           <animate attributeName="stop-color" dur="1.5s" values="yellow;dodgerblue;yellow" repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>       
   
        </linearGradient> 
  <linearGradient id="grad2" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="lime">
              <animate
                attributeName="stop-color"
                dur="1.5s"
                values="lime;purple;lime"
                repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>    
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="purple">
           <animate
             attributeName="stop-color"
             dur="1.5s"
             values="purple;lime;purple"
             repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>    
        </linearGradient>
 
     </defs>
<path id="path1" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z"  fill="url(#gradl)" stroke="none" fill-opacity="1" > 
 
</path>

<path id="path2" transform="rotate(45 150 150)" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z" fill="url(#grad2)"troke="none"; fill-opacity="0.8">
  
</path>
<circle cx="150" cy="150" r="90" stroke="none" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

**К анимации градиента добавляем вращение колец**

```css
svg {
background:black;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 300 300" > 
<defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradl" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"> 
             <animate
                attributeName="stop-color"
                dur="1.5s"
                values="dodgerblue;yellow;dodgerblue"
                repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>    
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow">
           <animate
             attributeName="stop-color"
             dur="1.5s"
             values="yellow;dodgerblue;yellow"
             repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>       
   
        </linearGradient> 
  <linearGradient id="grad2" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="lime">
              <animate
                attributeName="stop-color"
                dur="1.5s"
                values="lime;purple;lime"
                repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>    
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="purple">
           <animate
             attributeName="stop-color"
             dur="1.5s"
             values="purple;lime;purple"
             repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>    
        </linearGradient>
 
     </defs>
<path id="path1" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z"  fill="url(#gradl)" stroke="none" fill-opacity="1" > 
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 150 150;360 150 150"  dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
</path>

<path id="path2" transform="rotate(45 150 150)" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z" fill="url(#grad2)"troke="none"; fill-opacity="0.8">
 <animateTransform
   attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   values="360 148 148;0 148 148"
   dur="6s"
   repeatCount="indefinite" />  
</path>
<circle cx="150" cy="150" r="90" stroke="none" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

Добавляем текст и к нему тоже применяем градиент.

Если практически применять этот пример в верстке, то можно делать галерею, где статично лоадер мигает, а после клика появляется текст, фото и т.д , которые будут окружены крутящимися кольцами.

Запуск анимации по клику внутри SVG.

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}

svg {
background:black;
}

#path1 {
fill:url(#gradl);
stroke:none;
fill-opacity:1;
}
#path2 {
fill:url(#grad2);
stroke:none;
fill-opacity:0.8;
}
#crc1 {
stroke:none;
fill:black;
}
#txt1 {
fill:url(#grad2);

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 300 300" > 
<defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradl" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"> 
             <animate
               attributeName="stop-color"
               dur="1.5s"
               values="dodgerblue;yellow;dodgerblue"
               repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>    
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow">
           <animate
             attributeName="stop-color"
             dur="1.5s"
             values="yellow;dodgerblue;yellow"
             repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>       
   
        </linearGradient> 
  <linearGradient id="grad2" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="lime">
              <animate
                attributeName="stop-color"
                dur="1.5s"
                values="lime;purple;lime"
                repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>    
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="purple">
           <animate
            attributeName="stop-color"
            dur="1.5s"
            values="purple;lime;purple"
            repeatCount="indefinite"  /> 
             </stop>    
        </linearGradient>
 
     </defs>
<path id="path1" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z" > 
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 150 150;360 150 150" begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" /> 
</path>

<path id="path2" transform="rotate(45 150 150)" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z" >
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="360 148 148;0 148 148" begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" />  
</path>
<circle id="crc1" cx="150" cy="150" r="90" /> 
 <text id="txt1" x="80" y="160" font-size="36" font-weight="700" > Click me </text>
</svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: А если сделать просто окружности и вращать их с `transform-origin`, тогда может быть вполне похожий эффект, как и у @Air'a

Comment: @Arthur попробуй, но он просил на чистом SVG а `transform-origin` как я понимаю это CSS

Comment: Есть атрибут в `SVG`, но он не поддерживается в Mozilla, а есть решение с изменением x y в `rotate(deg x y)`

Answer (score 11):

Фигуры будут иметь сложные контуры и поэтому, чтобы избежать непредсказуемого поведения при вращении элементов SVG, очень важно сразу позаботиться о чётком определении центра вращения.

### Работа в векторном редакторе

Для задания / определения центра фигур сделаем несколько простых шагов:

- Создадим  файл SVG c двумя фигурами: прямоугольник и вписанную в него
  окружность

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">  

<rect x="30" y="30" width="240" height="240" stroke="black" fill="none" />
<circle cx="150" cy="150"  r="90" stroke="black" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

- Загружаем этот файл в векторный редактор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Центр вращения будет `150 Х 150px`

Чтобы трансформировать контуры прямоугольника в нужную фигуру, выбираем в меню векторного редактора `Контур / Оконтурить объект` <kbd>shift+Contrl+C</kbd>

- Добавляем по осям ещё 4 узла
- Выделяем все узлы фигуры  и выбираем - `Сделать выделенные узлы автоматически сглаженными`
  Получилась вот такая фигура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перетаскивая узловые точки и с помощью их рычагов добиваемся нужной формы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При перетаскивании необходимо следить, чтобы не сдвинуть всю фигуру. На картинке видно, что центр остался на месте `150 Х 150`

- Сохраняем файл. Забираем формулу патча `<path>d="M.... />`

### Создание кода прелоадера

Одно кольцо вокруг окружности

```html
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 300 300">  

    <path id="path1" fill="yellowgreen"  d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z"/>
    <circle cx="150" cy="150"  r="90" stroke="none" fill="black" />
    </svg>
```

Даем команду вращения `values="0 150 150;360 150 150"` - c 0 до 360 град. центр 150 Х 150

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 300 300">  

    <path id="path1" fill="yellowgreen"  d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 150 150;360 150 150" dur="6s"/> 
  </path> 
    <circle cx="150" cy="150"  r="90" stroke="none" fill="black" />
    </svg>
```

Добавляем второе кольцо, полученное из копии первого кольца и поворачиваем его предварительно на 45 град.

```
<path id="path2" transform="rotate(45 150 150)" fill="dodgerblue"
```

Запуск анимации обоих колец происходит одновременно, но они вращаются в разные стороны

```html
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 300 300">  

    <path id="path1" fill="yellowgreen"  d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 150 150;360 150 150" dur="6s"/> 
  </path>  
  
  <path id="path2" transform="rotate(45 150 150)" fill="dodgerblue" fill-opacity="1" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="360 150 150;0 150 150" dur="6s"/> 
  </path> 
   
   <circle cx="150" cy="150"  r="90" stroke="none" fill="black" />
    </svg>
```

Добавляем каждому кольцу градиенты, прозрачность

```css
svg {
background:black;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 300 300" > 
<defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradl" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow"/>   
        </linearGradient> 
  <linearGradient id="grad2" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="lime"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="purple"/>   
        </linearGradient>
  </defs>
<path id="path1" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z"  fill="url(#gradl)" stroke="none" fill-opacity="0.5" > 
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 150 150;360 150 150" dur="12s" /> 
</path>

<path id="path2" transform="rotate(45 150 150)" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z" fill="url(#grad2)"troke="none"; fill-opacity="0.5">
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="360 148 148;0 148 148" dur="12s" />  
</path>
<circle cx="150" cy="150" r="90" stroke="none" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7):

Многих пугают очень длинные строчки SVG кода.
 Тяжело психологически перейти от формата CSS свойств, где в каждой отдельной строчке один атрибут. 
Попробую написать атрибуты, команды `SVG` в стиле правил `CSS`
Заодно поменяю цветовую схему прелоадера:

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}

svg {
background:black;
}

#path1 {
fill:url(#gradl);
stroke:none;
fill-opacity:1;
}
#path2 {
fill:url(#grad2);
stroke:none;
fill-opacity:0.6;
}
#crc1 {
stroke:none;
fill:black;
}
#txt1 {
fill:url(#grad2);

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 300 300" > 
<defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradl" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="o.5"> 
     <animate 
     attributeName="stop-color" 
     dur="1.5s" 
     values="red;yellow;red"
     repeatCount="indefinite" 
     /> 
            </stop>    
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow">
           <animate  
       attributeName="stop-color" 
    dur="1.5s" 
    values="yellow;red;yellow" repeatCount="indefinite" 
       /> 
           </stop>       
   
        </linearGradient> 
  
    <linearGradient id="grad2" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="lime"> 
     <animate 
     attributeName="stop-color" 
     dur="1.5s" 
     values="lime;purple;lime"
     repeatCount="indefinite" 
     /> 
            </stop>    
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="purple">
           <animate  
       attributeName="stop-color" 
    dur="1.5s" 
    values="purple;lime;purple" repeatCount="indefinite" 
       /> 
           </stop>       
   
        </linearGradient> 
  
 </defs>
<path id="path1" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z" > 
 <animateTransform 
  attributeName="transform" 
   type="rotate" 
    values="0 150 150;360 150 150" 
  begin="svg1.click" 
   dur="10s" 
   /> 
</path>

<path id="path2" transform="rotate(45 150 150)" 
  d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z" >
 <animateTransform 
  attributeName="transform" 
   type="rotate" 
    values="360 148 148;0 148 148" 
  begin="svg1.click" 
  dur="10s" />  
</path>
<circle id="crc1" cx="150" cy="150" r="90" /> 
 <text id="txt1" x="80" y="160" font-size="36" font-weight="700" > Click me </text>
</svg>  
</div>
```